# Best way to program in C++ remotely through an vps via FTP/SSH

Tags: c++, ssh, ftp

For years, I had been using Notepad++ with nppFTP plugin for coding, which works amazing, it uploads them fastly by just pressing Alt+S, I also need to compile the code after the upload, I use PuTTY to achieve it via `cli`, I quickly swap windows and type `clear && make && ./app`(using up arrow to enter last command), but I lack or things such autocomplete, also view compiler errors in `cli` is messy.

Would be there a better option?

I'm running Windows 10, my VPSs run CentOS/Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried using [git](http://git-scm.com)? You can use some continuous deployment system with it or just write a hook that will compile on push.

Comment: hm, would it instant and efficiently pull changes once I edit any source file? if so, at least it would allow me to use any other IDE with autocomplete...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio totally supports remote development for linux and it absoluty fits what I were looking for, there is the guide that I followed:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/